# How to access previous app state/config on app relaunch (TornadoFx)

Tags: config, tornadofx

After looking at [state/settings, configuration](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/part2/Config%20Settings%20and%20State.html), I have tried `config` and `app.config` for app state/setting management. When I use `app.config`, I am able to access the state in other views.

I wish to implement state such that when the app is launched a second time, the first view or behavior should be different based on the state config/settings of the previous session.

I realized that each time I relaunch the app all states default to null.

I even came across the notion of `configBasedPath` and `configPath` but what I am not sure about is,

- if my app is to create them  automatically  or I need to do it manually
- If my app will automatically resolve the config path to `app.properties` or I will need to do it manually.

This is because after running my app, I do not see the default `conf` base directory and the `app.properties` file.

I am currently developing on windows 10 and use FXLauncher for packaging.

How can I persist state in my app such that I can always access the previous states/settings I run the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist configuration changes, simply call `save()` on the config object. To save the global app config settings, call `app.config.save()`. Changes are automatically loaded when the app starts.

You can read more about the config object in the guide:

https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part2/Config%20Settings%20and%20State.md